# How to make constructor that takes in 2 if there are 2 parameters, or 3 if there are 3

Tags: java, constructor

New to Java...

I have a name class that has:

```
private String firstName;
private String middleInitial;
private String lastName;
```

as its instance variables.

If I had certain data that had only firstName and lastName, no middleInitial, how would I make the constructor so that it took only 2 parameters instead of three?

Answer (score 10):

You simply write a constructor with two parameters and a constructor with three

```
public YourClass(String firstName, String lastName) {
   ...
}

public YourClass(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName) {
    ...
}
```

Callers can then choose to use the appropriate constructor based on their needs.

Answer (score 9):

Well, two options:

- Just have a constructor with three parameters, and call it using null or the empty string for `middleInitial`
- Overload the constructors, possibly calling one from the other.

As an example for the latter, using an empty string as the default middle initial:

```
public Person(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this(firstName, "", lastName);
}
```

However, the compiler will need to know which one you're *calling* from the call site. So you can do:

```
new Person("Jon", "L", "Skeet");
```

or

```
new Person("Jon", "Skeet");
```

... but you can't do:

```
// Invalid
new Person(firstName, gotMiddleInitial ? middleInitial : ???, lastName);
```

and expect the compiler to decide to use the "two name" variant instead.

Comment: Hint: I think you will score some extra upvotes when you provide a `getFullName()` method.

Comment: +1 For suggesting that the 2-argument constructor call the 3-argument constructor.

Comment: Defining, and documenting, the canonical constructor is a very good practice. Makes subclassing more understandable and concentrates initialization logic in one place. +1 to answer and @Brian

Comment: "Well, two options" -> there is the builder pattern also.. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, constructors can't have default arguments. Your only option here is to write two constructors. Fortunately, Java does allow you to call constructors from other constructors. You could do something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String firstName;
    private String middleInitial;
    private String lastName;

    public MyClass(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public MyClass(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this(firstName, "", lastName);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Class Name{
private String first;
private String middle;
private String last;

public Name(String first, String middle, String last){
this.first = first;
this.middle = middle;
this.last = last;
}

public Name(String first, String last){
this.first = first;
this.last = last;
}

}
```

Comment: This won't work. The second two constructors have the same signature (Name(String, String)), so it's ambiguous.

Comment: @jpm - thank you. That what happens if you are in a hurry. Removed the third one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two constructors:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this(firstName, null, lastName);
}

public Person(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName     = firstName;
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    this.lastName =    = lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define 2 constructors, one with 2 parameters and one with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two constructors.

```
public Person( String firstName, String lastName, String middleName ) { ... }

public Person( String firstName, String lastName ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void myBike(String name, String color)
{
      System.out.println("My bike's name is " + name + " and is " + color + ".");
}

public void myBike(String name, String color, float height)
{
      System.out.println("My bike's name is " + name + " and is " + color + ".");
      System.out.println("My bike is also " + height + " inches tall.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Builder pattern...

```
class Name {

            Builder builder;


            public String getSurname() {
                return builder.surname;
            }

            // getter...


            public Name(Builder builder) {
                this.builder = builder;
            }


            class Builder {

                String surname = "";
                String middleName = "";
                String name = "";


                Builder surname(String surname) {
                    this.surname = surname;
                    return this;
                }


                Builder middleName(String middleName) {
                    this.middleName = middleName;
                    return this;
                }


                Builder name(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                    return this;
                }


                Name build() {
                    return new Name(this);
                }

            }
        }
```